# Can you use custom docker image for Azure Pipelines when using the generic Git connection?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When using the GitHub connection with Azure DevOps pipelines I see that you can specify a docker image in your azure-pipelines.yml file (`vmImage:` option)

But when using generic git connection you only have a dropdown with just some options:
[image: agent specification dropdown for azure pipelines]

Is there any way to add custom docker images to be used? Since I would need different NodeJS version for different pipelines and here, ubuntu 18.04 image for example only has v10

Comment: Until now, we only expand the feature of Container job in YAML definition. For classic editor which shown like the pic you shared above, it does not support choose your customized image. Did you has any trouble with YAML?

Comment: I need to use the "Generic Git" connection since we don't host the code on GitHub. Is there any way to use YAML definition with non github projects?

Comment: Don’t need worry about the source project host server. All of the sources support YAML and classic at same time. In VSTS, we also support the git from Bitbucket and etc. Could you tell me that which host are you using? For our container job, it only has limitation on image agent type.

Comment: I'm currently using a private installation of BitBucket Server and another one of GitLab. I don't see how to edit the yaml file for "generic git" connection. I'm on https://dev.azure.com/my-account/ 1) I click new pipeline; 2) select other git; 3) I select empty pipeline template 3) here I don't see anywhere I can edit the yaml file; I can only configure the job in classic mode; Also what about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops it says YAML is not supported for generic git connection

Comment: Forgive my missing, for repos, if it hosted in server, it could not use YAML, also Container job will not available. The pic you showed in the question represents some Hosted agent type and could not be modified by users. If you want to use the customized docker image, you need change the **Agent pool** value as your private pool firstly. Then you could choose your image agent in the **Agent Specification**. But the condition is that you must have configured a private build agent which runs in a Docker container. What about the link in shayki's solution?

Answer (score -1):

The option to choose a docker container it's only the YAML pipelines that are [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops) in the other Git connection.

You can use a [Self Hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) agent and [run it in docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops), so you need to configure a few images in your environment and connect them to Azure DevOps.